# Проблема с кодировкой в запросе

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

имею такой код: https://pastebin.com/kBwdXSmq

На строке

```
<code lang="python">
sign = hmac.new(secret_key, msg=encoded_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper() 
</code>
```

получаю ошибку: `TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'`

Пробовал делать так:

```
<code lang="python">
sign = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf8'), 
msg=encoded_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper() 
</code>
```

Ошибка: `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Пожалуйста, помогите решить